# Emacs Lisp: getting ascii value of character

Tags: char, elisp, ascii

I'd like to translate a character in Emacs to its numeric ascii code, similar to casting `char a = 'a'; int i = (int)a` in c. I've tried `string-to-number` and a few other functions, but none seem to make Emacs read the char as a number in the end.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String is an array.

```
(aref "foo" 0)
```

Answer (score 16):

To get the ascii-number which represents the character --as Drew said-- put a question mark before the character and evaluate that expression

`?a` ==> `97`

Number appears in minibuffer, with C-u it's written behind expression.

Also the inverse works

`(insert 97)` will insert an "a" in the buffer.

BTW In some cases the character should be quoted

`?\"` will eval to `34`

Comment: Follow up question, what if I want to convert 97 into the character 'a' now?

Comment: Try for example: (insert 97)(print 97)(message "%c" 97)(eval 97)

Answer (score 8):

A character *is* a whole number in Emacs Lisp. There is no separate character data type.

Function `string-to-char` is built-in, and does what you want.  `(string-to-char "foo")` is equivalent to `(aref "foo" 0)`, which is @abo-abo's answer --- but it is coded in C.