# How to get code point of a character in elisp (and other way too)?

Tags: unicode, elisp, chr, ord

I was very surprised not to be able to find this in the elisp manual or SO. I just want the equivalent of many languages' chr() and ord() or similar: convert between actual characters and their (unicode) code point values.

[Emacs Lisp: getting ascii value of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862517/emacs-lisp-getting-ascii-value-of-character) explains that to elisp, a char just *is* its code-point. But what if I need the representation of that char~int as a series of ASCII decimal digits?

For example, if I wanted to generate in a buffer, a readable table showing the equivalences?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emacs Lisp: getting ascii value of character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862517/emacs-lisp-getting-ascii-value-of-character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've already noted, characters *are* integers.

```
(eq ?A 65)
```

> For example, if I wanted to generate in a buffer

Either of the following inserts the character `A` into the buffer:

```
(insert ?A)
(insert 65)
```

If you need to deal with *strings*, characters can be converted to strings:

```
(char-to-string ?A)
(char-to-string 65)
(format "%c" 65)
"A"
```

vs

```
(number-to-string 65)
(format "%d" 65)
"65"
```